# why is my jquery function not loading on page start?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function.
 I also have a variable, `$id_number`.

If the value in variable exists:

- I want the jquery function to load. This is a modal that should pop up on page start.

  ```
          <? if(isset($id_number))
          { ?>
              jQuery(document).ready(function(
          <? }
          else
          { ?>
              jQuery(function($){
          <? } ?>

              // code

           });
  ```

why is my function not loading on page start? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is that PHP code around it all?

Comment: Have you done debugging or inspecting the client-side code in a browser?

Comment: Showing the generated code would be more useful. Examples should be *complete*. Also, those two jquery calls are equivalent, as you can read in the documentation. There is no need for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

         <? if(isset($id_number))
            { ?><script>
                alert('dummy');
                </script>
            <? }
            else
            { ?>
                <script>
                alert('data');
                </script>
            <? } ?>
```